# Why does AppCompatTextView showing wrong text in layout designer?

Tags: android

As you see in the picture there is text in the `AppCompatTextView`  left design view.
To the right in setting pan I clearly set the text like:

```
android:text="some text"
```

Any ide?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `TextView` instead of `AppCompatTextView`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView.html):

> This will automatically be used when you use TextView in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should **only** need to manually use this class when writing **custom views**.